# PHP/MySQL / Use String to SELECT from Database

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a string:

```
 $string = "12,15,22";
```

Each of these values represents a usrID and I'd like to use these to select the rows associated with the $string.

Something like this:

```
SELECT usrFirst, usrLast FROM tblusers WHERE usrID = 12 OR 15 OR 22.
```

Now, the $string changes all the time, and sometimes can be a different number of ID's.  Eg., sometimes 3, sometimes 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use IN, although it is very slow if you have lots of numbers:

```
SELECT usrFirst, usrLast FROM tblusers WHERE usrID IN ($string)
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) has more info on IN.

If you have lots of numbers, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220142/how-to-optimize-this-mysql-slow-very-slow-query) for info on how to speed this up.

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the values if they are coming from any form of user input.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

SELECT usrFirst, usrLast FROM tblusers WHERE usrID in (12, 15, 22);

Answer (score 1):

you can also do:

```
$string = str_replace(',',' OR usrID=',$string);
mysql_query('SELECT usrFirst, usrLast FROM tblusers WHERE usrID='.$string);
```

Comment: -1 That ends up being SELECT usrFirst, usrLast FROM tblusers WHERE 12 OR usrID = 15 OR usrID = 22;

Comment: So add usrID= before it. It was a simple, easily correctable error on my part.