# Counting children in another table for each row

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables: `CATEGORY` and `SUBCATEGORY`

Table Structure for `CATEGORY`

```
category_id         int(11)  
category_name       varchar(250) 
category_status     enum('0', '1')
```

Table Structure for `SUBCATEGORY`

```
subcategory_id      int(10) 
subcategory_name    varchar(255)    
status              enum('0', '1')
```

For example there is a single `CATEGORY` named .NET and it has entries in `SUBCATEGORY` like ASP.NET, VB.NET, C#.NET . In this case I need to get the count of `CATEGORY` as 1 and the count of `SUBCATEGORY` as 3 using MySQL.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Huh? This is confusing. Please show your table schema using SHOW CREATE TABLE. Here are some useful tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204402/how-do-i-ask-for-help-optimizing-fixing-queries-in-mysql

Comment: Whoa Eric, wtf? You seem to have gone a bit overboard with the edits there. Why did you change his intro and remove the beginner tag?

Comment: @hobodave: I think the `beginner` tag is superfluous and nearly meaningless. If you'd like to have a discussion as to why, head on over to Meta. Aside from that, I changed the question to fix grammar. Also noticed that I missed a lingering "am," so I'll change that, too. "I am a newbie" really has no bearing on answering the question.

Comment: Just seems obtuse to remove someone's greeting, as well as the thanks at the end.

Comment: @hobodave: See Meta for more info on it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can do it with a subquery. However, you'll need to add a `category_id` column to the `subcategory` table, so that we know what subcategories go with which categories. Then, you can get what you want with the following query:

```
select
    category_name,
    1 as CategoryCount,
    (select count(*) from subcategory where category_id = c.category_id) as SubCategoryCount
from
    category c
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need Eric.. Thanks for your timely HELP.

Comment: @Fero: Glad to help. Feel free to mark this as the answer, since I'm at -1 right now. It helps for those crazy Googlers.

Comment: +1 This solution works. Not sure why it was down voted earlier.

Comment: Eric.. This is my first day in stack over flow.. will u please help me how to MARK THIS AS ANSWER.

Comment: @Fero: There's a little check mark to the left of the answer, just under the arrows. Once you check that, you've marked an answer.

Comment: one more query eric.. is there any possibilites to close this query

Comment: As in this question? Nope, we leave it up for the rest of the world, so they can solve the same problems you've come across.

Answer (score 1):

Since we can assume category count is one and there's more than likely a key constraint on category_id between the two tables, this will work as well:

```
select c.category_id, count(c.category_id) 
from category c
inner join subcategory s on (c.category_id = s.category_id)
group by c.category_id
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can up vote answers by clicking on the up arrow to the left of each answer as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CATEGORY;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SUB_CATEGORY;
```

I don't believe that's exactly what you're going for, but that's all you're really gonna get without a foreign key.