# Simple MySQL Query taking 45 seconds (Gets a record and its "latest" child record)

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

I have a query which gets a customer and the latest transaction for that customer. Currently this query takes over 45 seconds for 1000 records. This is especially problematic because the script itself may need to be executed as frequently as once per minute!

I believe using subqueries may be the answer, but I've had trouble constructing it to actually give me the results I need.

```
SELECT
    customer.CustID,
    customer.leadid,
    customer.Email,
    customer.FirstName,
    customer.LastName,
    transaction.*,
    MAX(transaction.TransDate) AS LastTransDate
FROM customer
INNER JOIN transaction ON transaction.CustID = customer.CustID 
WHERE customer.Email = '".$email."'
GROUP BY customer.CustID
ORDER BY LastTransDate
LIMIT 1000
```

I really need to get this figured out ASAP. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: run on mysql the query "EXPLAIN your_query_here;" the results might help you.

Comment: Try running EXPLAIN <our query> on the actual server and posting the results.

Comment: Yes, please show EXPLAIN and the table structure. I also suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204402/how-do-i-ask-for-help-optimizing-fixing-queries-in-mysql

Comment: @clyfe: Apparently we agree. @Brian Lacy: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html for an explation of output (change 5.1 to relevant server version).

Comment: I think you may have a bigger problem.  The transaction.* is going to return random values from some transaction record for the customer but not necessarily the ones from the record with the maximum transaction date.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @Larry Lustig: I was just pondering the same. I could see it working as intended though, as transaction with max(date) probably has highest id. But it is relying on unspecified behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have an index for `transaction.CustID`, and another one for `customer.Email`.

Assuming `customer.CustID` is a primary key, this should already be indexed.

You can [create an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html) as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_transaction_CustID ON transaction(CustID);
CREATE INDEX ix_customer_Email ON customer(Email);
```

As suggested in the comments, you can use the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) command to understand if the query is using indexes correctly.