# MySQL doesn't use indexes in a SELECT clause subquery

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, subquery

I have an "events" table

```
table events
  id (pk, auto inc, unsigned int)
  field1,
  field2,
  ...
  date DATETIME (indexed)
```

I am trying to analyse holes in the trafic (the moments where there is 0 event in a day)

I try this kind of request

```
SELECT
    e1.date AS date1,
    (
        SELECT date
        FROM events AS e2
        WHERE e2.date > e1.date
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS date2
FROM events AS e1
WHERE e1.date > NOW() -INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

It takes a very huge amount of time

Here is the explain

```
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys       | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t1    | range | DATE                | DATE                | 6       | NULL |        1 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t2    | ALL   | DATE                | NULL                | NULL    | NULL | 58678524 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Tested on MySQL 5.5

Why can't mysql use the DATE indexe? is it because of a subquery?

Comment: How many rows are there in your `events` table?

Comment: approx 60 millions

Comment: may be a typo **WHERE e1 > NOW() -INTERVAL 10 DAY**. should be this : `WHERE e1.date > NOW() -INTERVAL 10 DAY`

Comment: I fixed the query (thx)

Comment: Would you please tell us what you are trying to do? May be restructuring the query might use index.

Comment: Is not that it is not using an index, but you sare making a subquery per row,  approx 60 millions  of subquery is a thing that you should avoid.

Comment: No it is not.

I have a WHERE clause (e1.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY) wich select only a small portion of the 60M rows.

And trying to link 1 row in the subquery for each fetched row... should be approximatively the same that simply joining a table...

Comment: First, let's figure out what you are trying to do.  The subquery can return _any_ date grater than `e1.date`.  Perhaps you wanted the smallest?  If so, add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Or, you are really just doing an `EXISTS` test?  But I don't see a `HAVING`?

Answer (score 1):

Your query suffers from the problem shown [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,104645,104645#msg-104645) which also presents a quick solution with temp tables. That is a mysql forum page, all of which I unearthed thru finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8916127) Stackoverflow question.

You may find that the creation and populating such a new table on the fly yields bearable performance and is easy to implement with the range of datetimes `now()` less 10 days.

If you need assistance in crafting anything, let me know. I will see if I can help.

Comment: Thx, but I understand that MySQL is still not ready for working with SUBQUERIES...  

I have to find an alternative way to analyse holes in trafic

Comment: Well let me know if I can help. Not sure what holes in traffic means, unless you mean related to your event and next event issue (gaps)

Comment: Holes are gaps. I want to detect periods without trafic 

The other way of achieving this is to GROUP BY SUBSTR(date, 1, 16). I will have all minutes with trafic. And I will find with this query the gaps with an external script.

Comment: I am happy to help. But i need sample data, and expected results, showin in tabular form

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for dates with no events?

First build a table `Days` with all possible dates (`dy`).  This will give you the uneventful days:

```
SELECT dy
    FROM Days
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM events
                        WHERE date >= days.day
                          AND date  < days.day + INTERVAL 1 DAY )
      AND dy > NOW() -INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

Please note that 5.6 has some optimizations in this general area.

Comment: this is the alternative I am going to apply... But it's disapointing that MySQL 5.5 doesn't handle this kind of subqueries.

If I have more time, I will try to do a test againt 5.6 or 5.7

Thx for the help