# Mysql Explain Query with type "ALL" when an index is used

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, explain

I ran a query in Mysql like below:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM(
        SELECT *  # Select Number 2
        FROM post
        WHERE   parentid = 13
        ORDER BY time, id
        LIMIT 1, 10
    ) post13_childs
JOIN post post13_childs_childs
ON post13_childs_childs.parentid = post13_childs.id
```

and the result was:

```
id |select_type  |table               |type |possible_keys  |key      |key_len  |ref              |rows    |Extra
1  |PRIMARY      |<derived2>          |ALL  | NULL          | NULL    |NULL     |NULL             |10      |
1  |PRIMARY      |post13_childs_childs|ref  |parentid       |parentid |9        |post13_childs.id |10      |Using where
2  |DERIVED      |post                |ALL  |parentid       |parentid |9        |                 |153153  |Using where; Using filesort
```

This means it used the index `parentid` but scaned all rows due to `ALL` and `153153`. 
Why could not the index help to not `Full Scannig`?

Although if i run the derived query (Select #2) **alone** like below:

```
Explain
SELECT * FROM post  
WHERE parentid=13
ORDER BY time , id
LIMIT 1,10
```

the result would be desired:

```
id |select_type  |table  |type |possible_keys  |key      |key_len  |ref  |rows    |Extra
1  |SIMPLE       |post   |ref  |parentid       |parentid |9        |const|41      |Using where; Using filesort
```

#### Edit:

The table `post` has these indexes:

1. id (PRIMARY)
2. parentid
3. time, id (timeid)

count of total rows --> 141280.
count of children of `13` (`parentid=13`) --> 41
count of children of `11523` --> 10119

When i add index of `(parent,time,id)`, problem of first query would be solved by the explin output for `13` --> 40 rows, type:ref
and for `11523` --> 19538 rows, type:ref!!! this Means all children rows of `11423` is examined while i limited first 10 rows.

Comment: Do you want help improving and optimizing this query? If so, we would need to see the whole query (and its EXPLAIN)

Comment: @Strawberry, Excuse me. I edited and wrote details now.

Comment: Try creating index for `(parentid, time, id)`. For further reference http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: You cannot take advantage of index in the derived table....

Comment: @Meherzad, Why? Realy? is a reference available .

Comment: Try using `explain extended` with your query it will return a detailed explain statement [refer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html) and for your question [refer](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/31/derived-tables-and-views-performance/)

Comment: @ahoo [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180714/how-can-i-further-optimize-a-derived-table-query-which-performs-better-than-the) this question with similar problem.... Hope this helps.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62d36/2) it will answer all your question. Index is not used withing derived table

Comment: OK, tnx @Meherzad, it is reason for slow query `Select#1`. My problem is `Select#2` and `type:All`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a composite index on (parentid, time, id) ??

Comment: @Meherzad, When i create index (parentID, time, id ), the column rows of explain result output 19538 (and type:ref). I Expect 10 due to LIMIT clause.

Comment: need some `show create table [table_name]` outputs of both tables we cant solve it like this...

Answer (score 10):

Your subquery:

```
    SELECT *  # Select Number 2
    FROM post
    WHERE   parentid = 13
    ORDER BY time, id
    LIMIT 1, 10;
```

This mentions three columns explicitly, plus all the rest of the columns  You have three indexes.  Here is how they can be used:

- id (PRIMARY) -- This index is useless.  Although mentioned in the `order by` clause, it is the second condition
- parentid -- This index can be used for satisfying the `where` clause.  However, after the correct data is pulled, it then would need to be sorted explicitly.
- time, id (timeid) -- This index can be used for the sort, with a big BUT.  MySQL can scan the index to get everything in the right order.  But it will have to check, row-by-row, whether the condition on `parentid` is met.

Just to introduce why optimization is hard.  If you have a small amount of data (say the table fits on one or two pages), then a full table scan followed by a sort is probably fine.  If most of the `parentid` values are `13`, then the second index could be a *worst* case.  If the table does not fit into memory, then the third would be incredibly slow (something called *page thrashing*).

The correct index for this subquery is one that satisfies the `where` clause and allows ordering.  That index is `parentid, time, id`.  This is not a covering index (unless these are all the columns in the table).  But it should reduce the number of hits to actual rows to 10 because of the `limit` clause.

Note that for the complete query, you want an index on `parentid`.  And, happily, an index on `parentid, time, id` counts as such an index.  So, you can remove that index.  The `time, id` index is probably not necessary, unless you need that for other queries.

Your query is also filtering only those "children" that have "children" themselves.  It is quite possible that no rows will be returned.  Do you really intend a `left outer join`?

As a final comment.  I assume that this query is a simplification of your real query.  The query is pulling all columns from two tables -- and those two tables are the same.  That is, you will be getting duplicate column names from identical tables.  You should have column aliases to better define the columns.

Comment: tnx for replying. i added index `parentid, time, id` but ... (look at my Edit of my above Question which i changed now)

Answer (score 1):

Doing an ORDER BY that is not helped by any index can regularly kill performance.  For the inner query, I would have a covering index on (parentID, time, id ) so that both the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses can utilize the index.  Since the parentID is also the basis of the join afterwords, it should be good to go there to and be quite fast.

Comment: @ahoo, no, now a pair of (time,id), you NEED TO INCLUDE THE Parent ID, so the index should be (PARENTID, TIME, ID)

Comment: When i index `(parentID, time, id )`, the column `rows` of explain result output 19538 (and type:ref). I Expect 10 due to `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: @ahoo, I would suggest deleting the individual parentID and (timeid, id ) to avoid confusion to the engine as the one index with parentID in the FIRST POSITION of the index would do the same as your stand-alone index, but by also having the time and id as second and third position will resolve the order by clause.

Comment: parentID is defined as a foreign key. all foreign keys is index too. and i don't think can delete index of it.